# Insert variable Javascript in a Choices input object

Tags: javascript

Question is simple.

I have a form made with choices.js

For create a multiple select, I use this code (from Choices Github)

```
 var multipleCancelButton2 = new Choices('#choices-sites', {
    removeItemButton: true,
     choices: [
        {value: 'Child ', label: 'Child ', selected: false},
        {value: 'Child site', label: 'Child ',  disabled: true},
        {value: 'Child Three', label: 'Child Three'},
    ],
```

Edit information about (it is my code):

```
   $.each(hotels, function(i, item) {
    var myObject = { value: item.name, label: item.name, selected: 'false' };
    choicesJsonh.push(myObject);

});

 var textRemove = new Choices('#choices-hotels', {
   editItems: true,
  removeItemButton: true,
   choices: choicesJsonh,
 });
```

Comment: What does the variable hotels contain. And does item.name give a value or give undefined? That could be a possible explanation of the failing.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the choices array is not a string. Don't try to treat it as a string!

If you want to create a new object then:

```
var myObject = { value: item.name, label item.name, selected: false };
```

If you want to add that to an array then:

```
myArray.push(myObject);
```

You can combine the two statements:

```
myArray.push({ value: item.name, label item.name, selected: false });
```

Then put the array itself into the object you pass to the Choices function:

```
var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices-hotels', {
 removeItemButton: true,
 choices: myArray,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am working in it however it not working yet. Show you my code now in other answer.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas — I refer you back to the last code block (and explanatory text proceeding it) of my answer.

Comment: Ok, was a problem with the structure of my app. You answer was correct. Thank you very much!